# Can I run IPV6 L3VPN over MP-BGP IPV6?

Tags: cisco, ipv6, mpls

I am looking for information about how to implement IPV6 L3VPN over MP-BGP IPV6 but i can see only IPV6 L3VPN over MP-BGP IPV4 (dual stack). 
When I implement ipv6 l3vpn over mp-bgp ipv4, I activate address-family vpnv6 under ipv4 neighbor, but I can't see vpnv6 under ipv6 neighbor.

Comment: What device and software version are you using?  BTW, you don't "run" MPLS or anything else over MP-BGP.  BGP just advertises reachability.

Comment: Not many router operating systems implement MPLS on top of IPv6. All MPLS networks run on top of IPv4, with dual stack on top of MPLS.

Comment: Ron Trunk,
Device is ASR9006 and software is IOS-XR 5.3.3 
Now, I run mpls on top ipv4 and run mp-bgp for l3vpn. I try to configure ipv6 like ipv4 but i can't.

Sander Steffann,
you mean best practice is run mpls on top of ipv4  with dual stack right?